# Como comprobar si un div no tiene contenido

Tags: javascript, html

queria saber como puedo comprobar si un div esta vacio por medio de javascript sin usar jquery solo con javascript puro.

Porque he buscado y solo con jquery lo logro encontrar y lo necesito solo con javascript puro.

Comment: Deberías compartir tu código, además de modificar tu etiqueta ya que colocaste "Java" en vez de "Javascript".

Comment: @BDOM Es que no tengo codigo hecho porque no se como hacerlo solo con javascript puro

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo asi:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  if(divs[i].innerHTML == "") {
    console.log(divs[i].id);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <label>Hello</label>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```